# How to implement try/except with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Not all eBay listings are the same because some pages use different format than others. I want my code to find the "price" element and if it doesn't exist, then try a different approach. 
I created the code below but I was wondering what is a better method?

```
try:
    if len(soup.find('span', {'class': 'vi-qtyS-hot-red'}).text) > 0:
        total_sold_price = soup.find('span', {'class': 'vi-qtyS-hot-red'}).text
    else:
        total_sold_price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mm-saleDscPrc"]').text 
except Exception as e:
    total_sold_price = ""
```

Entire Code: https://pastebin.com/bV12WbXv

Comment: you could assign to variable `item = soup.find()` and then check `if item: price = item.text` and then this part of code will not raise error.

Comment: What is throwing if you take off the `try-catch`? Why are you mixing soup and Selenium?

Comment: Probably shouldn't catch the base `Exception`. Catch what you expect, ie whatever is thrown when you don't find the price.

Comment: Also try looking at [webdriverwait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html), which helps with waiting until an element is found, and throws an Exception if the element is not found